# WIN32 select() reports exception on listen() socket; WSAGetLastError() = 0?

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, network-programming

Title maybe says it all?

Windows 10, Visual Studio Community 2017.

A C++ server listens on a port, and the resulting FD is put in an fd_set for input, and one for exceptions.  `select()` is called.

It returns, and a connection is `accept()`ed.  Its FD is also added to those two fd_sets.

The connection goes fine, and ends.  Its FD is then removed from the two fd_sets.

Upon the next call to `select()` I'm told there is an exception on the listening socket, but `WSAGetLastError()` is zero.

The listening FD has `O_NONBLOCK` set, according to my notes, because:

> There may not always be a connection waiting after select or poll
>   return a readability event, because there might be a subsequent
>   network error.  To prevent `accept()` from blocking we must set
>   `O_NONBLOCK`.

It also has `SO_REUSEADDR` set.

`listen()` has a queue depth of 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`getsockopt()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738544(v=vs.85).aspx) on the listening socket with option `SO_ERROR`.

The zero from `WSAGetLastError()` refers to the `select()` not returning -1.